# Returning a value from within a class loading method (images/audio)

Tags: javascript

For my current **game-development** project, I'm using pure `JS` and `HTML5 Canvas`, no `jQuery`, nothing of the sort.

I have X images to load at the beginning of a level. So far, I've been using the load handler on them to increment a counter (which counts how many images are loaded) until the counter value is X.

Once it's done, it begins to draw things on the Canvas.

Now, I've reached the stage where I'm trying to pass as much stuff into it's own specific class as possible. My issue is that if I put all the loaders into the classes, I'm not sure how I can check if that counter is at the correct value.

My idea was to create something like this:

In `GameLevel.js`:

```
function init(player,level,actors,enemies)
    var loaded_components = 0;
    if (player.initializeImages==true)
        loaded_components++;
    if (level.initializeImages==true)
        loaded_components++;
    (...)
    if (loaded_components==5)
        initiateDrawing();
```

In, for example, `Player.js`:

```
initializeImages(){
    loaded=0;
    maxload=10;
    this.idle.addEventListener("load",loadHandler);
    this.idle.id = "idle";
    this.idle.src = "path/idle.png";
    (...)
    loadHandler(ev){
        if (ev.id == "idle")
            loaded++;
        (...)
        if (loaded==maxLoad){
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

So, the issue here is: I'm not sure how to make the code stop at that test for the return value of the `initializeImage()` method. I want the loading of all things to be placed within the specific class of the thing being loaded, if that makes sense.

I also know that you can load things without checking, and I've been doing that with the audio to test, but it's unsafe, and I really want to change it! I'm rather new to it, but if anyone has a solution that works, I'd love to hear about it.

Thanks in advance!

---

Edit: Tried it, but I'm failing!

I have a class that receives a few Canvasses, draws to them, and only once these are drawn should the code move forward.

I tried making a promise within the constructor, so it would be:

```
constructor(layer1,layer2,layer3,layer4){
   this.layer1 = layer1;
   (...)
   var promise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
         **(load everything here)**
         **(once everything is loaded, draw to the
         multiple canvasses referenced above)**
         **(all done, resolve)**
   });
}
```

This didn't work. I tried making the promise outside, in GameLevel.js, in the following way:

```
(in gameLevel):
   var promise = new Promise(..){
           scene = new Scene(layer1, layer2 (...))
           resolve("done");
   promise.then(function(){
           beginGame();
  }
```

This also does not work, the promise isn't... Waiting, for the scene to finish it's full creation and initialization. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd return `Promise` from the `init` method and simply wait for all Promise to complete.

Comment: Building off what @appleapple said, you can join all the `Promises` together and subscribe to the join, which won't fire until all of them have resolved.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: I believe that is exactly what I needed! Thank you so much, and thank you for the link!

Comment: @appleapple would you mind having a look at the edit? I've ran into an issue... Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something about promises. Appreciated

Comment: You need to return the promise. Besides, canvas draw is sync function, it doesn't need to use Promise.

Comment: I just post a simple game(?) as answer, please checkout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a example with loading and rendering loop.

```js
function loadimage(src){
  return new Promise(resolve=>{
    let img = new Image();
    img.onload = ()=>resolve(img)
    img.src=src
  })  
}

function stageinit(){
  let imagesPromise = [
    loadimage('https://via.placeholder.com/150'),
    loadimage('https://via.placeholder.com/300')
  ]
  return Promise.all(imagesPromise)
}

stageinit().then(images=>{
    //images are loaded, do whatever you want

    let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
    let x = 0
    function gameloop(){
      requestAnimationFrame(gameloop)
      ctx.fillRect(0,0,500,500)
      ctx.drawImage(images[0],x,0)
      ctx.drawImage(images[1],x,200)
      x+=1
    }
    gameloop()
  }
)
```

```css
canvas{width:80vmin;height:80vmin;border:3px solid yellow}
```

```html
<canvas width=500 height=500></canvas>
```